# Como eu faço para inserir na pagina uma informação que esta no excell

Tags: python

Boa tarde pessoal, gostaria de saber se alguém pode me ajudar ...

Estou automatizando uma pagina e gostaria de saber se é possível eu utilizar uma planilha de excell para popular os campos ...

por exemplo:

Hoje eu estou utilizando o seguinte comando abaixo, ele insere no elemento `mname` a informação mariano, esta eu inseri manualmente.

```
driver.find_element_by_id("mname").send_keys("mariano")
```

o que eu preciso? 
Preciso que ao invés desse mariano, ele busque uma informação que esta em uma planilha do excell, assim eu utilizarei o excell como parâmetro sem necessidade de mexer no meu script

```
driver.find_element_by_id("mname").send_keys("Dados da coluna A2 do Excell")
```

Desde ja muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Se você utilizar um CSV no Excell, consegue fazer isso com manipulação de arquivos direto ou com o módulo [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html), que faz parte da biblioteca padrão. Se usar o formato xlsx, vai precisar de um [módulo externo](http://www.python-excel.org/) para ler o arquivo. Há vários.

Comment: Obrigado Cochise, vou estudar aqui e ver se tenho um bom resultado ... abçs

Comment: Boa tarde Cochise , deu certo ... muito obrigado.

book = xlrd.open_workbook("planilha.xls")
sh = book.sheet_by_index(0)

Utilizei essa rotina dentro da função..

driver.find_element_by_id("fname").send_keys(sh.cell_value(rowx=2-1, colx=1-1))

Answer (score 1):

```
import xlrd

book = xlrd.open_workbook("planilha.xls")
sh = book.sheet_by_index(0)

def test_e_cadastroI(self, mem_dc=None):
driver.find_element_by_id("fname").send_keys(sh.cell_value(rowx=2-1, colx=1-1))
```

......

Comment: Poderia explicar o seu código? Mesmo que pareça trivial, nem todos os usuários conseguirão entendê-lo. Uma explicação em texto sobre a lógica da sua solução só trará melhorias para a sua resposta.

Comment: import xlrd --> * Importando a Biblioteca xlrd, se trata a leitura da arquivos externos

book = xlrd.open_workbook("planilha.xls") --> *Criei uma variável informando à ela o arquivo que estou utilizando , é necessário que o arquivo esteja na mesma pasta onde se encontra o .py*

sh = book.sheet_by_index(0)

def test_e_cadastroI(self, mem_dc=None):

driver.find_element_by_id("fname").send_keys(sh.cell_value(rowx=2-1, colx=1-1)) --> rowx e colx se refere a linhas e colunas respectivamente.